# Adding manually a legend element - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

With the code below:

```
plt <- ggplot(data) + geom_step(aes(factor(no), var7, color = group_no, group = group_no), size = 1.6)
plt + geom_step(aes(factor(no), var5, color = group_no, group = group_no), linetype = 'dashed', size = .7)
```

I have generated the following plot.
[image]

Now I would like to modify legend in one of the following way:

- add the legend  for color and dashed line
- add two dashed lines to the ones already visible on the legend and modify their explanation so that they would show for example 'id 1, var5', 'id2, var 5' for dashed lines and 'id1, var7', 'id2, var7' for solid lines (actually, this one is preferable)

Is it feasible? I have tried with `scale_linetype_manual(values = c('var5', 'var7')` but it didn't work.

The data look like this:

```
data <- structure(list(no = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), group_no = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), var1 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), var2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0), var3 = c(2.04466646181187, 0.660598114091747, 1.55142947390572, 
1.53055726052766, 1.33062973767801, 0.521466633696396, 0.383486796026974, 
0.320273289219046), var4 = c(0.786548055557462, 0.933132594335315, 
0.734844331310191, 0.404908113668656, 0.50963171017644, 0.066048513105941, 
0.156065948976073, 0.528480184907794), var5 = c(2, 1, 3, 
2, 4, 2, 5, 3), var6 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1), var7 = c(2.04466646181187, 
0.660598114091747, 3.59609593571759, 2.19115537461941, 4.92672567339561, 
2.71262200831581, 5.31021246942258, 3.03289529753485), var8 = c(0.786548055557462, 
0.933132594335315, 1.52139238686765, 1.33804070800397, 2.03102409704409, 
1.40408922110991, 2.18709004602017, 1.93256940601771)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), vars = "group_no", drop = TRUE, .Names = c("no", "group_no", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8"), indices = list(c(0L, 2L, 4L, 6L), c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L)), group_sizes = c(4L, 4L), biggest_group_size = 4L, labels = structure(list(group_no = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L), vars = "group_no", drop = TRUE, .Names = "group_no"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, here is an option for your first request

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
 gather(variable, value, c(var5, var7)) %>% 
 ggplot() + 
 geom_step(aes(factor(no), 
               value, 
               color = group_no,
               linetype = variable,
               group = interaction(group_no, variable),
               size = variable)) +
 scale_linetype_manual(values = c('var5' = "dashed",
                                  'var7' = "solid")) +
 scale_size_manual(values = c('var5' = 1,
                              'var7' = 2)) +
 guides(size = "none")
```

Reshape your data from wide to long format and map `color` to 'group_no' and `linetype` to 'variable'. The `interaction` is necessary because the group is not defined by a single variable anymore, but by a combination of 'group_no' and 'variables'.

Change the `size` of the lines using `scale_size_manual` after you mapped 'variable' to this aesthetic. Add `+ guides(size = "none")` such that the different `size`s of `geom_step` is not displayed in the legend.

[image]

Comment: Cool, but is it now possible to plot thicker solid lines (approx. twice the size of dashed lines)? I have tried to use `size = key` but well, it didn't look good.